# ng-class in ng-repeat: conditional class names depending on the item parameters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

In a `ng-repeat`, I'd like to set the class names of a `ng-class` depending on some item parameters.

Simple example where I wanted to add the **gender** and the **age** corresponding class to each `<li>`:

```
<div ng-init="friends = [
  {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Mary', age:28, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Peter', age:95, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Sebastian', age:50, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Erika', age:27, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Patrick', age:40, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Samantha', age:60, gender:'girl'}
]">
  I have {{friends.length}} friends. They are:
  <input type="search" ng-model="q" placeholder="filter friends..." />
  <ul class="example-animate-container">
    <li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:q" ng-class="friend.gender friend.name">
      [{{$index + 1}}] {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work that way.

Any idea of how to simply achieve that ?

Comment: What is the problem? http://plnkr.co/edit/hqCmwK3ohDah6ZaZj3Md?p=preview

Comment: true, thanks for the Plunker example @dfsq ! I just made this simple example up to replicate the bug I had in a more complex app, didn't actually try the example... In my app, there are actually several classes to be added the same way. This doesn't work: `ng-class="friend.gender friend.name"`. Plunker updated: http://plnkr.co/edit/jUOUHHcfftFcel0mEo4K?p=preview

Comment: Oh, I see your problem now. See my answer how to use `ngClass` in this case.

Comment: updated my post with several parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ng-class` also supports array notation if you want to add multiple classes like in your case:

```
ng-class="[friend.gender, friend.name]"
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/c6NIaF2dO5pmJxbj1WRT?p=preview

Comment: you're a star ! thanks a lot for your quick answer !! updated my first post accordingly.